# How to render a menu_block in a specific language (i18n)

Tags: theming, i18n-l10n, blocks

I have a special menu that is part of the page. I include it in the template like

```
$block = module_invoke('menu_block', 'block_view', DEF_BOOKLETS_MBID);
print render($block['content']);
```

Menu's are part of the interface, not of the content. If I use i18n, the translated menu will appear fine if the *interface language* switches.

However, the client does not want that. The interface is supposed to be one language, but the content can switch languages. That works too - apart from the menu block inside the content.

Is there a way to render a menu_block inside a template in the current *content* language ?

Comment: {{crickets!!}} the reason why this is important, is because, if I switch the interface language, `some` of the interface of the site (like 'log out') gets translated automatically, while `most` of the interface (like 'click here dude') does not. breaks the site.

Comment: {{crickets}} moreover, the whole admin menu gets translated, which makes the client get totally lost.

Answer (score 0):

ok - this is extremely ugly, but seems to work

```
global $language,$language_content;
$org_language = $language;
$language = $language_content;
$block = module_invoke('menu_block', 'block_view', IAF_BOOKLETS_MBID);
$language = $org_language;

print render($block['content']);
```

Feel free to boo me on this one :-D